# How to Kill Surviving mutation JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mutation-testing

I have this code

```js
const writeToDB = async (data) => {
    console.log("Inside db put")
    try {
        const resp = await dynamoDB.put(data).promise();
        console.log("Data added db: ", resp);
        return "successfully inserted"
    } catch (err){
       throw new Error(`Failed to write in database`, err)
  }
}
```

I have 2 tests for this functionality one to check when its sucessful and one where it throws an error.
When I run stryker I get a surviving mutation

```js
    - } catch (err){
    -   throw new Error(`Failed to write in database`, err)
    - }
     + } catch (err){}
```

I believe this is trying to find a test  "if it catches the error but does not throw the error".
How do I write a test to kill this particular Blockstatement mutation. The code is always going to throw the error that I have specified.

Comment: Please post your existing test cases, especially the one for the error case.

Comment: @Bergi there is no error  in the test. So I have  1st test that test the return of "successfully inserted" message and another test that verifies that the error is thrown. Mutation run is showing that there is a surviving mutation so what additional test is needed to kill it.

Comment: "*test that verifies that the error is thrown*" - that one. Please post the code of both test cases.

Comment: This is one of the test where I am verifying the error
```
it("test failed to write in database", async () => {
    const error = new Error("Failed to write in database")
    const metadata = await mm.createObject(event.detail)
    stubAWSCall(
      sinonSandbox,
      AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient.prototype,
      "put",
      metadata.Item,
      true,
      error
    )
    return mm.putMetadataItem(metadata).catch(err => {
        assert.throws(() => {
          throw error
        }, err)
      })
  })
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include it, so you can use proper formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mutation test is entirely correct. The approach

> ```
> return mm.putMetadataItem(metadata).catch(err => {
>   assert.throws(() => {
>     throw error
>   }, err)
> })
> ```

to check for the expected behaviour of the `putMetadataItem` function is wrong. In particular, if the returned promise is not rejected, the `.catch()` callback with your assertion doesn't run at all, and the fulfilled promise is returned, which causes the unit test to pass. Also `assert.throws` is rather pointless here, you know for sure that `throw error` will throw, so all this does is to check equality between `error` and `err`.

You would need to write

```
return mm.putMetadataItem(metadata).then(() => {
  throw new AssertionError('expected putMetadataItem() to reject');
}, err => {
  assert.equal(error, new Error('Failed to write in database'));
});
```

however you actually should use [`assert.rejects`](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_rejects_asyncfn_error_message):

```
return assert.rejects(() => {
  return mm.putMetadataItem(metadata);
}, new Error('Failed to write in database'));
```

Comment: Thank you. I am now able to understand what is needed and why it was not killing the mutation